# C++ Thread in an unordered_map (no copy constructor)

Tags: c++, unordered-map, deleted-functions

I am trying to figure out a way to get a thread out of an unordered_map in c++.

However, I am getting the *std::thread::thread(const std::thread &) attempting to reference a deleted function*.

Example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <unordered_map>
#include <thread>

class ThreadContainer
{
    std::unordered_map<int, std::thread> map_;
public:
    void addThread(int handle, std::thread thread)
    {
        map_.emplace(std::move(handle), std::move(thread));
    }

    std::thread getThread(int handle)
    {
        return map_.at(handle);
    }
};

int main()
{
    ThreadContainer testing;

    return 0;
}
```

In this code example I have tried `return map_.at(handle);` and `return std::move(map_.at(handle);` neither of these seem to work.

How can I get the std::thread back out of this unordered_map?

Comment: _"I'm guessing..."_  Your guess is wrong.  _"If that is true..."_ That is not true.  What is your real question?  What are you trying to ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::thread getThread(int handle)
```

is a function that returns by value. This requires a non-deleted copy constructor. As you've noted, `std::thread`'s copy constructor has been deleted.

Solution: Return by reference

```
std::thread & getThread(int handle)
```

and make sure the receiver is also a reference. Do not force copying at any point in the chain.

If by "get the std::thread back out of this unordered_map" you want to remove the `thread` from `ThreadContainer` you could

```
std::thread&& removethread(int handle)
{
    return std::move(map_.at(handle));
}
```

but this will leave a "dead" thread in `map_`. You will probably want to remove the key and the now-unattached `thread`.

```
std::thread&& removethread(int handle)
{
    std::thread temp(std::move(map_.at(handle)));
    map_.erase(handle);
    return std::move(temp);
}
```

Also note that `ThreadContainer` will not be copyable because the contained `thread`s cannot be copied. You will get much more readable error messages if you `delete` `ThreadContainer`'s copy constructor and assignment operator.